# How to yield rich.progress from another python script using with statement?

Tags: python-3.x, rich

I have a basic rich progress bar implemented like this:

```
import time

from rich.progress import *

with Progress(TextColumn("[progress.description]{task.description}"),
              BarColumn(), TaskProgressColumn(),
              TimeElapsedColumn()) as progress:

    total = 20
    for x in range(total):
        task1 = progress.add_task(f"[green]Processing Algorithm-{x}.",
                                  total=total)
        progress.update(task1, advance=1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

It works as expected.

But now I want to remove the initialization the the progress bar in a separate file, so I
created a file task_progress.py and put the code in there.

```
from rich.progress import *
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def init_progress():
    yield Progress(BarColumn(), TaskProgressColumn(), TimeElapsedColumn())
```

And I updated the original progress bar as below:

```
import time

from task_progress import init_progress

with init_progress() as progress:

    total = 20
    for x in range(total):
        task1 = progress.add_task(f"[green]Processing Algorithm-{x}.",
                                  total=total)
        progress.update(task1, advance=1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

But, now when I run the code the progress bar does not appear on the terminal!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap the creation of the `Progress` class in a context manager. The Progress class can already act like a context manager. A function that returns an `Progress` object will work fine:

```py
from rich.progress import *


def init_progress():
    Progress(BarColumn(), TaskProgressColumn(), TimeElapsedColumn())
```